# Double scroll bar in iframe with jQuery Fancybox (2.0.5.)

Tags: jquery, fancybox, phpbb3

I've got a realy anyoing problem. I've used the newest Fancybox to open my phpBB3 forum in a pop-up screen. When I do so, I've got a double scrollbar on the right of the pop-up. You can see it in action right here:

[Bellewaerdefun](http://www.bellewaerdefun.be)

Now click the "forum" button in the top navigation and you will see what I mean. I realy don't know what I'm doing wrong. With the old Fancybox version, it worked very well!

Here's my js code:

```
$('.forum-popup, ul#forum-topics li a').fancybox({
    type                : 'iframe',
    margin              : 30,
    padding             : 7,
    scrolling           : 'auto',
    width               : '100%',
    height              : '100%',
    openEffect          : 'fade',
    closeEffect         : 'fade',
    fitToView           : true,
    closeBtn            : true,
    closeClick          : false
});
```

Anyone who had the same problem or anyone who can help me with this beauty problem? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tries to set the iframe height to the same height as the content it's content in order to make it scrollable. But it seems as if it dowsn't work correctly and the page inside of the iframe has still got it's all scrollbar. Setting scrolling to `no` will probably fix the issue.

Comment: That does the trick. But in fact, I've got a little sub problem now: there's a +/- 250px whitespace at the bottom of the iframe. In fact, theiframe get a height on it's element style: 1375px. This appears only when opening the fancybox. After you clicked the forum logo, it's gone... Very strange, but thanks for the solution!